# How to bind to a dropdown list with no value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have written some code to do a bulk update of a gridview. In the gridview one of my template fields has a drop downlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCategories" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="odsCategories" DataTextField="txtCategory" 
  DataValueField="intCategoryID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("intCategoryID") %>'>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select an item" Value ="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In my database I have 800 records. However only a few of them have been assigned the value of "intCategoryID". The rest are NULL.

The whole reason of the bulk update is to update all of the "intCategoryID" fields and assign a category ID to each record.

Because not all od the "intCategoryID" have been assigned a value I am getting an error when I try to render the page. The dropdown list is failing. Here is the message:

```
'DDLCategories' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

Is there a way I can assign the empty categories to the list item that has a value of "-1" I have created in the dropdownlist? IE If the "intCategoryID" ISNULL then have "Please Select an item" selected, otherwise select the selected value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://blog.evonet.com.au/post/2008/06/07/dropdownlist1-has-a-SelectedValue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-list-of-items.aspx).  It overrides the binding method for the DDL and checks for the missing SelectedValue.  You may have to modify it if you're not using a FormView, but I think you'll get a good start with that post.

Comment: Apologies: the link is now dead, and I shouldn't have provided a link only answer to begin with. @Jason, feel free to unaccept.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"This site can’t be reached / blog.evonet.com.au’s server DNS address could not be found"* | [OP Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84520/jason?tab=profile) seems inactive since July 2016 :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to convert the code you pointed out to me, however I am still only new to C# and ASP.NET therefor I have some errors.

The code you pointed out refers to a formview, however I am tring to change it to a gridview.

Here is my code so far:

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)(GridView1.DataItem);
        if ((rowView != null) &&
            ((DropDownList)(GridView1.FindControl("DDLCategories")).Items.FindByValue(rowView["intCategoryID"].ToString()) != null));
        {
            (DropDownList)(GridView1.FindControl("DDLCategories")).SelectedValue = rowView["Category"].ToString();
        }
    }



protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValues["intCategoryID"] = (DropDownList)(GridView1.FindControl("DDLCategories")).SelectedValue;
}
```

Could you please point out when I am creating errors.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to allow AppendDataBoundItems and add a an intem that corresponds to null. It could have the value of "-1" or any other value you is not on your list values. Now all you have to do is make a conditional binding:

```
(Eval("intCategoryID") != null && Eval("intCategoryID").ToString().Length>0) ? Eval("intCategoryID").ToString() : "-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, you can create a custom DropdownList server control.

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomNamespace
{
    // Dropdownlist which does not throw an exception if SelectedValue does not exist
    public class CustomDropdownList : DropDownList
    {
        protected override void PerformDataBinding(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource)
        {
            try
            {
                base.PerformDataBinding(dataSource);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the custom dropdownlist on the aspx page instead. If your project was called "CustomProject", add this on the second line of the aspx file:

```
<%@ Register assembly="CustomProject" namespace="CustomNamespace" tagprefix="custom" %>
```

Then replace all DropdownList tag instances with the custom one:

```
<custom:CustomDropdownList ID="ddlId" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("column") %>' DataSourceID="dataSourceDropdown" DataTextField="field" DataValueField="value" />
```